# Error "Missing \endcsname inserted." when using package "program" before "tikz-cd"

Tags: tikz-cd, program

The code

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{program} % from sn-jnl.cls
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

yields the error
`Missing \endcsname inserted. ...eoperator{||}{or} {2}{infix} {200}` in file `pgfmathparser.code.tex` of my `texlive` installation.

The error is gone when the `\usepackage` lines are swapped. However, in my actual use case, I cannot change the order, because `\usepackage{program}` is part of a publisher's `.cls` file that I have to use unaltered.

How can I fix this document without swapping these lines?

I am aware of the answer of [Conflict between tikz-pgf and program](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368251/conflict-between-tikz-pgf-and-program) , but don't know whether this could help me here.

(I can give more details on my environment if needed, but I see this on Windows and Linux.)

Comment: program is a menace, as is the fact that sn-jnl.cls includes it. Put `\catcode\`\|=12`  after the package to restore `|`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Great, that fixed it! Do you want to make your comment into an answer for the rep points?

Comment: actually I gave a better answer here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619280/springer-nature-2021-class-causes-error-when-writing-x/619283#619283

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`program` unfortuately makes `|` globally active, you can put

```
\catcode`\|=12
```

after the package to restore `|`